# Printing RDD to a text file with Header

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Simple problem:
For the following RDD I want to print out an output text file with the following format and header (UserID,MovieID,Pred_rating )

```
scala> final_predictions_adjusted.sortByKey().first
res61: ((Int, Int), Double) = ((1,1172),1.8697903970770442)
```

Simple enough. right? so I am using this function:

```
  def print_outputfile(final_predictions_adjusted:RDD[((Int, Int), Double)])={
    val writer = new FileWriter(new File("output.txt" ))
    writer.write("UserID,MovieID,Pred_rating")
    final_predictions_adjusted.sortByKey().foreach(x=>{writer.write(x.toString())})
    writer.close()
  }
```

The above function is not working with the following error

```
caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.FileWrite
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked like sweet lords will:

```
  def print_outputfile(final_predictions_adjusted:RDD[((Int, Int), Double)])={
    val writer = new FileWriter(new File("output.txt" ))
    writer.write("UserID,MovieID,Pred_rating\n")
    final_predictions_adjusted.sortByKey().collect().foreach(x=>{writer.write(x._1._1+","+x._1._2+","+x._2+"\n")})
    writer.close()
  }
```

Comment: the `collect` result will be on the driver only.  That's OK as long as the result's small enough to fit there but won't work with large datasets

Answer (score 0):

With your code the FileWriter object would be send to all nodes and executed in parallel, which does not work with the reference to the local file. Therefore you get the NotSerializableException.

You would typically save the RDD to a file by saveAsTextFile:

```
final_predictions_adjusted.sortByKey().map(e=> (e._1._1,e._1._2,e._2)).saveAsTextFile("output.dir")
```

This writes out the file in multiple parts. You could add the header and combine the parts manually later.

Comment: Wow. Even better. If I use `final_predictions_adjusted.sortByKey().collect().foreach(x=>{writer.write(x.toString())` thans for explaining the error